# Pass a method inside a symbol in Map function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, dictionary, methods

someone could explain me, How can I pass a method inside a symbol that give me Map.
This is my method

```rb
def visited_venues
  Profile.find(1432).bookings.map(&:venue).uniq
end
```

now I want to do something like

```rb
def visited_venues
 Profile.find(1432).bookings.map(&:venue.kept).uniq
end
```

that returns me all undiscarded in my DB, when Im trying to do it, always return me `undefined` because Venue is a symbol.
Thanks for any help and explanation.

Comment: If you have to call a chain of methods you need to pass a block. Passing a symbol is just a shortcut. Alternatively you can call map twice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
Profile.find(1432).bookings.map(&:venue.kept).uniq
```

Try

```
Profile.find(1432).bookings.map { |booking| booking.venue.kept }.uniq
```

Testing in Pry with

```
["hi", "bye"].map(&:upcase) -> ["HI", "BYE"]
["hi", "bye"].map(&:upcase.downcase) -> ["HI", "BYE"]
```

Remember that

```
(&:method) is just a shortcut for { |el| el.method }
```

Comment: thanks @TedTran2019, it will be the best solution, thanks